# Tools to compute graph edit distance (GED)

Tags: graph, edit-distance

I read a lot of theory on computing graph edit distance (GED), or other graph similarity measures (such as http://goo.gl/gmDMgA) but I'm failing to find tools to accomplish such computations.

Is there a programming library or softwares that computes graph edit distances, or, once again, any other graph similarity measures, between two graphs?

Answer (score 6):

There are at least three possibilities for software to compute graph edit distance:

> **[GEDEVO](http://gedevo.mpi-inf.mpg.de/)**, is a software tool for solving the network alignment problem.
>   GEDEVO stands for Graph Edit Distance + EVOlution and it utilizes the
>   evolutionary computing strategies for solving the so-called Graph Edit
>   Distance problem.
>
> **[graph mapping distance matrix generator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/preafum/)** is parallel Java code which generates a graph mapping distance matrix. It is related to frequent subgraph mining based on the REAFUM algorithm.
>
> **[GRAPH EDIT DISTANCE : A NEW BINARY LINEAR FORMULATION](https://sites.google.com/site/blpged/binary-files)** from the paper [New binary linear programming formulation to compute the graph edit distance](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S003132031730300X)
>
> ** You can find other Python, Java, and C++ implementations by searching [sourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/) and [gitHub](https://github.com/explore).

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/haakondr/graph-edit-distance-python

I implement one by myself. It's not that hard. See "BRIDGING THE GAP
BETWEEN GRAPH EDIT DISTANCE AND KERNEL MACHINES".

Comment: Great, have you got a short set instructions to try it with a few graph?

Comment: The one on the github? Not yet.

Comment: Or in general, which function to use, what file format, things like that :)

Comment: @Zhongjun'Mark'Jin did you followed this paper for this implementation http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1543687 could you please share documentation for your code? Do you know any implementation for latest papers from Riesen Kaspar?

Comment: @Vishrant This is exactly what I was referencing when trying to implement a ged. See the comment. Sorry, I was not aware of the papers from Riesen Kaspar.

Comment: @Zhongjun'Mark'Jin Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[GMatch4py](https://github.com/Jacobe2169/GMatch4py)

It has multiple algorithms with additional functions beyond GED. The repository has instructions and examples. The install is also pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

you can use python module like below:

```
import networkx as nx 

nx.grah_edit_distance(g1,g2)
```